# performance reading nested hierarchy

Tags: performance, hdf5

I have a performance problem while reading the attributes from an hdf file.. it seems it takes almost 1.5 minutes to read attributes(10 each) from about 18000 groups/datasets .. hoping somebody can tell me if this is a reasonable time indeed for such a structure... 
the hdf file has some 300 groups under root 
each of these 300 groups(T) have about 60 subgroups(V) and each of these 60 subgroups have 1 or 2 datasets(D)

```
   Root 

       ----- T1 

            ----- V1 
                 ---- D 

            -----  V60 
                  ---- D 

         .... 
         .... 
         .... 

      -----  T300
```

at each level I am reading max 10 tiny attributes..

does reading each group mean mostly a new disk seek? my initial thinking is that since metadata belongs to different groups..they possibly end up on different disk blocks
I am thinking of creating a dataset of all metatadata

vtune shows large wait times opening groups and data sets
 ..any suggestions for improving performance.. ?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata for each object (group or dataset) are normally stored in the object header, so, as you say, it's likely that they are on different disk blocks. However, as you've found, this can lead to poor performance if you have a large number of attributes you need to read. Your idea of making a dataset of all the attributes has actually been implemented in HDF5. This is called "dense attribute storage" and can be turned on using [`H5Pset_attr_phase_change`](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetAttrPhaseChange). There is some example code [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/13_Attributes.html#SpecIssues).

You will need to use this function on every group and dataset. It's not clear from the reference manual if it creates one dataset for all the objects with dense attribute storage, or one for each of them. Possibly this depends on the file driver.

Lastly, if dense attribute storage doesn't give you much of a speed-up, you may consider parallel IO.